# Is there a way to specify a reg in nginx's server_name?

Tags: nginx

I have various domains, all started with 'XYZ', say XYZ123.de, XYZabc.hk, etc.
is there a way to specify in server_name:

server_name XYZ*, www.XYZ*;

possible,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server_name variable can be defined using exact names, wildcard names, or regular expressions. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html for examples.